# Use Woocommerce product categories even without Woocommerce installed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom plugin that when activated, it will create WooCommerce product categories. I use this code here to add a product category.

```
$category = array(
        'taxonomy'    => 'product_cat',
        'cat_name'    => 'Stimulants GROUP 1 (MPH Short acting, IR)',
    );

wp_insert_category( $category );
```

I tried activating my custom plugin without WooCommerce installed and it doesn't work. Will it not really work? If not, is there any other way to do so?

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? Are you seeing any error messages? Is the `product_cat` taxonomy not being inserted into the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO it will not work as simple as that…

> **Important Note**:
>   Woocommerce Product category is a custom taxonomy `'product_cat'` that **will only work** on Woocommerce "product" custom post type, but not for other posts…

The WordPress [`wp_insert_category()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_category) **will not work with any custom taxonomy**. This function is used for Wordpress categories…

For woocommerce product category, you will have to use [**`wp_insert_term()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term) instead this way:

```
wp_insert_term( 'Stimulants GROUP 1 (MPH Short acting, IR)', 'product_cat' );
```

If your custom plugin has been made for Woocommerce, you need to enabled Woocommerce. Don't forget that product category work exclusively with **"product"** post type.

> You can also create your own custom taxonomy `'product_cat'` with [this tutorial](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/create-custom-taxonomies-wordpress/) for example… But if your custom plugin needs Woocommerce, it will not solve anything.

---

**Answering your comment:** Prevent a plugin from activating if WooCommerce is not active?

Your main plugin file should start with:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

// Check if WooCommerce is active
if ( ! in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) exit; // Exit if WC not active
```

Or you can check this related thread: 
[How to check if a plugin (WooCommerce) is active?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/193907/how-to-check-if-a-plugin-woocommerce-is-active/284407#284407)

Comment: Ohh I see. If you don't mind, may I know how to prevent a custom plugin from activating if WooCommerce plugin doesn't exist? I tried to search many times already but I can't seem to make it work using their codes :/. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidMaranga I have added a little update at the end of my answer…

Comment: It's now working! Thank you very much @LoicTheAztec !

Answer (score 0):

The custom taxonomy `product_cat` is not something that belongs to WooCommerce. Any plugin can create and use the particular category in WordPress.

So, the [`wp_insert_category`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_category) function code that you have written will create that taxonomy.

To check why it does not work, you need to turn on the debugging mode by setting the [`WP_DEBUG`](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) constant to be true. Go through the logs and you will be able to trace the actual cause.